Como puedo hacer que un controlador inserte los datos proporcionados en un form?
Hola comunidad tengo una duda con respecto a como hacer que el form haga push a la base de datos eh inserte los datos proporcionados en la tabla lo que pasa es que segun yo ya tendo el insert correcto y necesito correrlo para que cuando entre a la seccion de new User me pida rellenar un formulario pero cuando intento entrar a esa seccion me aparece lo siguiente: **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@UserN nvarchar(4000),@Password nvarchar(4000),@Role nvarchar(4' expects the parameter '@UserN', which was not supplied.'
** por lo que lei del error me dice que esta esperando que le pase el parametro pero nunca recive algp lo cual no pasa por que ni siquiera carga la vista segun mi teoria es que carga el controlador antes de que la vista cargue y no me deja hacer el proceso correctamente entonces me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que esto no pase quisiera que esta funcion de insert en la tabla pasara despues de que se llenan todos los datos dentro del form no se si el evento onclick() tambien funciona en VB dejo mi codigo para saber que esta mal
        Dim password As String
        Dim Nombre As String
        Dim Puesto As String
        Dim role As String

        ' Obtener los valores del formulario
        UserN = Request.Form("userN")
        password = Request.Form("password")
        role = Request.Form("Role")
        Nombre = Request.Form("Nombre")
        Puesto = Request.Form("Puesto")

        ' Query para insertar los valores en la base de datos
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO IntranetSecurity (UserN, Password, Role, Nombre, Puesto) VALUES (@UserN, @Password, @Role, @Nombre, @Puesto)"
        Using command As New SqlCommand(query, cnn)
            ' Agregar parámetros para prevenir inyección SQL y asegurar la integridad de los datos
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserN", UserN)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", role)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Nombre)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Puesto", Puesto)

            ' Abrir la conexión y ejecutar el comando
            cnn.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
        Return View() ``` 

